# Restarting setInterval after using clearInterval in Javascript

Tags: javascript, button, setinterval, clearinterval

I am trying to make it so that there are two buttons using Javascript, one to stop the image carousel using clearInterval which works well, however, I also want another button to restart the carousel however I can't figure out how to do so.

```
<img src="images/img1.jpg" id="images" width="200px">
<button type="button" id="stop">Stop the Carousel</button>
<button type="button" id="start">Start the Carousel</button>

<script>
document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click', stopit);

var start = 1;
var timer = setInterval(carousel, 2000);

  function carousel(){
    var image_data;
    start =  start % 5;
    image_data = "images/img" + (start+1) + ".jpg";
    document.getElementById('images').src=""+ image_data;
    start++;
  }

  function stopit(){
    clearInterval(timer);
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Just put your current code into a click handler of a start button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your timer start logic to its own function:

```
<img src="images/img1.jpg" id="images" width="200px">
<button type="button" id="stop">Stop the Carousel</button>
<button type="button" id="start">Start the Carousel</button>

<script>
document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click', stopit);
document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', startIt);
var start = 1;
var timer

  function carousel(){
    var image_data;
    start =  start % 5;
    image_data = "images/img" + (start+1) + ".jpg";
    document.getElementById('images').src=""+ image_data;
    start++;
  }
  function startIt(){
     if(timer) stopit()
     timer = setInterval(carousel, 2000);
  }
  function stopit(){
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
  startIt() //if you want it to start automatically
</script>
```

Comment: What if you click twice on start?

Comment: "...another button to restart the carousel" - It seems carousel should start by default on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code there start, stop and restart button as well I hope it's useful.

if you click restart button then first carousel image comes it means it's work beginning.

Thanks

```
<img src="images/img1.jpg" id="images" width="200px">
<button type="button" id="stop">Stop the Carousel</button>
<button type="button" id="start">Start the Carousel</button>
<button type="button" id="restart">Restart the Carousel</button>

<script>
document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click', stopit);
document.getElementById('restart').addEventListener('click', restart);
document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', start);

    var start = 1;
    var timer = setInterval(carousel, 2000);

      function carousel(){
        var image_data;
        start =  start % 5;
        image_data = "images/img" + (start+1) + ".jpg";
        document.getElementById('images').src=""+ image_data;
        start++;
      }

      function stopit(){
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
      function start(){
        timer = setInterval(carousel, 2000);
      }
      function restart(){
        start = 1;
         timer = setInterval(carousel, 2000);
      }
    </script>
```